# Bind interface to implementation after login in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

I need to perform one Interface to implementation binding after the user logs into the application. While logging in user selects an environment and based on which the binding needs to be performed. I have added the following binding to `AppServiceProvider`, but seems like this is booted before the login is performed.

```
$providerClass  = 'App\Models\\' . ucfirst($provider);

        $this->app->bind(
            'App\Repositories\MyRepository',
            $providerClass
        );
```

Is it possible to bind this from controller or what will be an alternate method to bind the interface to corresponding implementation based on the environment selected by the user ?

Comment: Although creative, this is a bad idea. The bindings in the service container should not be depend on the application state. You could however create a factory which returns an implementation depending on application state.

Comment: I guess you can consider laravel register pattern here. Please read more about here http://rizqi.id/laravel-registry-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PtrTon said although it's a creative idea this is a bad idea. You can consider the laravel register pattern here.

**Registry Class:**

```
class EnvironmentGatewayRegistry {

  protected $gateways = [];

  function register ($name, EnvironmentGateway $instance) {
    $this->gateways[$name] = $instance;
    return $this;
  }

  function get($name) {
    if (in_array($name, $this->gateways)) {
      return $this->gateways[$name];
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Invalid gateway");
    }
  }

}
```

Your service provider

```
$this->app->singleton(EnvironmentGatewayRegistry::class);

$this->app->make(EnvironmentGatewayRegistry::class)
      ->register("dev", new DevImplemetaionClass())
      ->register("prod", new ProdImplemetaionClass());
```

In your controller/anywhere you want you can inject the class `EnvironmentGatewayRegistry` and call get method with register name like `dev`, `prod` as a parameter.

For more reference please check this document http://rizqi.id/laravel-registry-pattern

Comment: perfect. This solves my issue. Thanks for sharing this @vijaykumar.